# WKB to feature class in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, feature-class, well-known-binary, azure

I have a table in azure databricks called `prod.locations` that I am connecting to in ArcGIS Pro through an OLE DB Connection\Microsoft OLE DB Provider for ODBC Drivers. This table has a column called `geometry_wkb` and another called `geometry` that look like this in table view in ArcGIS Pro:

[image]

This is how the same columns look when I query them in databricks directly:

[image]

In this particular table there are about 200k records, but there are other tables with more that I would like to do a similar exercise with.

I'd like to be able to turn this table into a line feature class, and hopefully do this on a regular basis to always have fresh spatial data.

I've come across the `FromWKB` ArcPy function, but I am having a hard time finding examples I can effectively backwards logic for my data given my novice ArcPy knowledge. I also get the feeling that `FromWKB` is just one part of the process and won't create or insert all the records iteratively.

How/what should I be doing to reach my desired output?

Comment: First off, do you want to convert the WKB (binary data) or WKT (ASCII)?  (The  `geometry` column shows as WKT.)  OLE/ODBC doesn't permit geometry, but a Direct Connect connection might (natively).  Converting is as simple as creating a correct `SpatialReference` (parameter to `arcpy.FromWKB` or `arcpy.FromWKT`), then using an `arcpy.da.InsertCursor` to populate ***all*** columns in the target feature class.

Comment: I'll convert whichever one is the "easiest"-- would that be WKT since I can see the geometry column in arc through the current connection? Would you be able to show how to set that up? I have never used arcpy.da.InsertCursor either.

Comment: Just because you *see* it as WKT doesn't mean it is. If ArcGIS sees it as geometry, you can just use FeatureClassToFeaturecClass to copy the table. Learning to use a DA InsertCursor is way less than an hour's effort (and the documentation has multiple examples). Give it a try before asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

First you will need a feature class to store the table from Azure's geometry.

https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/data-management/create-feature-class.htm

You'll also need some cursor to iterate over you table. I don't know if you are using something like pyodbc. I would get the geometry column values in a list.

Then you can use an insertcursor on the newly created feature class.

```
with arcpy.da.InsertCursor("new feature class",["SHAPE@"]) as ic:
    for wkt in data_table_geometry_list:
        geom = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt,spatial_reference_object)
        ic.insertRow([geom])
```

Relevant links:
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/fromwkt.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/arcpy/data-access/insertcursor-class.htm
https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/classes/spatialreference.htm